# Asynchronous volley calls in android SyncAdapter

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, android-syncadapter

I implemented SyncAdapter using volley library. It is working, but then I realized that Iam calling asynchronous (volley request) code from onPerformSync method.

- Q1: coudl be onPerformSync executed multiple times in parallel? (for one user / one authority). Do I need to write inner code concurency safe? use lock? synchronization? Isn't SyncAdapter synchronized by itself, so any inner synchronization would be useless?
- Q2: is onPerformSync thread safe, which thread? It seems to me that all onPerformSync calls was done by the same thread reference. Does it mean that SyncAdapter is actually reused by system multiple times?
- Q3: is it safe to end onPerformSync before sync code is finished? (volley calls could take much longer than just create volley request, run it, and finish)

```
    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // time consuming code
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
        // onPerformSync end reached before volley request processing ends
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountDownLatch`  but i've read that's not a good way to implement in sync adapter how ever it works for me

```js
    
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    
    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // time consuming code
                        //put this line as the last line when everything is done
                        doneSignal.countDown();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
        try {
            doneSignal.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // onPerformSync end reached before volley request processing ends
    }
```